# Как вытащить 15% от суммы заказа в python?

Tags: python

```
# Чаевые
# Подсчитывает проценты от всей суммы

lunch = float(input("How much did you spend?"))
total = lunch % 15
print ("Here it is", total)
```

что происходит не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще можно было погуглить... очень уж банальный вопрос

```
lunch / 100 * 15
```

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `%` при использовании с числами возвращает остаток от деления. Для получения 15% суммы нужно умножить на `0.15`:

```
lunch * 0.15  # 15% от числа
```